# Taylor series of $f(z)=e^{1-2z}$ around $z_0=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Im trying to get the Taylor series of $f(z)=e^{1-2z}$ around $z_0=1$.

What I tried was $$e^{1-2z}=e\cdot e^{-2z} = e \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-2)^n (z-1)^n}{n!}.$$

But when I compute what it says is that the Taylor serie of $f(z)$ around $1$ is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-2)^n (z-1)^n}{n!\cdot e}.$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $e^{-2z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-2)^n z^n}{n!}$. How did $z^{n}$ sudddenly become $(z-1)^{n}$?

Comment: Hint: $e^{1-2z}=e^{-1}e^{-2(z-1)}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm MMm I get $(z-1)^n$ because im working around $z_0=1$

Comment: You cannot change $z^{n}$ to $(z-1)^{n}$ simply because you want the series around $1$.  You have to jusitify the equality.

Comment: @OlgaGonzalez: Just a minor arithmetic error: $1-2z=1-2(z-1+1)=-1-2(z-1)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks! I understand

Comment: @Mittens thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$e^{1-2z}=(1/e)e^{2(1-z)}=\frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^k(z-1)^k}{k!}$

---

Or: $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(z-1)^k$

$\frac{d}{dz}e^{1-2z}=(-2)e^{1-2z}$

$f'(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k c_k(z-1)^{k-1}=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(z-1)^k$

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)c_{k+1}(z-1)^k+2c_k(z-1)^k=0$

$\implies \frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}=\frac{-2}{k+1}\implies c_k= \frac{(-2)^k}{ek!}$

Answer (score -1):

The OP was on the right track, just a minor arithmetic error:
$$1-2z=1-2(z-1+1)=-1-2(z-1)$$
Then
$$e^{1-2z}=e^{-1}e^{-2(z-1)}=e^{-1}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n!}(-2)^n(z-1)^n$$